# Migration site with Azure Application Insights

Tags: azure, migration

We are currently using Application Insights in our self-hosted web app, and we are trying to migrate the app to a new VM hosted in Azure.  In this case is there anything I need to do to make my Application Insight to continue to work? Do I need to white list the new VMs?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to configure Application Insights to only accept data from certain IPs. So you don't need to whitelist anything in Application Insights.

If anything, you might want to keep track on what outgoing traffic your VM has. In this case, you need to [whitelist Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-addresses) in that direction.